# BASH scripting - not the expected output?

Tags: bash, curl, echo, counter

Hi I have here two text files, boy.txt and girl.txt

the values from boy.txt are:

```
12345678
87654321
```

the values from girl.txt are:

```
35f1f125-5d33-44a4-82fc-26734843c804
5abd0360-c4be-4e69-8085-340755f87290
```

I have to use these two values inside curl command, this is my command:

```
readarray boy < boy.txt
readarray girl < girl.txt

count=0
for i in ${girl[@]}
do
result[${boy[${count}]}]=${i}
count=$((count+1))

for output1 in ${!result[@]}; do
output2=${result[$output1]};


echo "curl -X PUT 
--header \"Content-Type: application/json\" 
--header \"Accept: application/json\" 
--header \"Authorization: Bearer gAAAAJ1EY28EHByJCcgT-sWhzid- cxW1uQrfO1QJG52D4n9GYj9YWd4KUGBSxO2LXZ48eEbQivSAlM6bplNE82o84UFnkwiVJ0V1q4DM9VAHw6jU4UvkdhhSrlupC6gKl_RHEgf2cluwvAN11My7eFflA-JnBrINp02d146CaJrR_r52hAEAAIAAAAAXmL1IDoHPz3S5deta0ygANUUoEFBsuKHaeDo3NXVUptxxDXR00yaNmILqd1psJckYhrBhh7wdQNdNYaSsqgwsF8Nuw_hhUAbg27hhGaVLmbeK3eS3mtVlq1D73Vg3KSk-24DmR0o-jT2u88k4MLfkqxuipEsLAEcSoe4zAPE1jcch2GGvlNWTHN98gMxw-svmvu6hizZ1fe-pWNtMGwa9u_hVimOr8A-7HcidA4Sj_jBprulGUapifc-Dd_qZFj1FM1HedHvnu8NKzp_uRr8z_Myk0IO6RyqjPPufLdafV3N4hmEqVex8P8jr4SkZWT0f-4i1epfZcRJmz6ognOCfaxa91c3qFNpG3IVY881g9aCPdLOxmU5FqKDPgHIZLvp8wWeTWdi_YQaAXMUh-yZQXBLhBimG8SR2iRj6ZTvu_L_Ytmc0QePkaijA6CB8wY2SbHlOGL2JUcEXKoNjC9dSSbkHqWx0tXMR2XCCdlhHPC1vGYcCgV-XQ_bfqgN7yn8\" 
-d \"\\"\"referenceId:"$output2"\\"\"\" \"https://website.com:443/testing/api/devices/"$output1"/parentPath\" " > test.sh

done
done

chmod+x test.sh

./test.sh
```

The output from command above is:

problem is only one curl command gets echoed instead of two

```
curl -X PUT 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" 
--header "Accept: application/json" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer gAAAAJ1EY28EHByJCcgT-sWhzid-cxW1uQrfO1QJG52D4n9GYj9YWd4KUGBSxO2LXZ48eEbQivSAlM6bplNE82o84UFnkwiVJ0V1q4DM9VAHw6jU4UvkdhhSrlupC6gKl_RHEgf2cluwvAN11My7eFflA-JnBrINp02d146CaJrR_r52hAEAAIAAAAAXmL1IDoHPz3S5deta0ygANUUoEFBsuKHaeDo3NXVUptxxDXR00yaNmILqd1psJckYhrBhh7wdQNdNYaSsqgwsF8Nuw_hhUAbg27hhGaVLmbeK3eS3mtVlq1D73Vg3KSk-24DmR0o-jT2u88k4MLfkqxuipEsLAEcSoe4zAPE1jcch2GGvlNWTHN98gMxw-svmvu6hizZ1fe-pWNtMGwa9u_hVimOr8A-7HcidA4Sj_jBprulGUapifc-Dd_qZFj1FM1HedHvnu8NKzp_uRr8z_Myk0IO6RyqjPPufLdafV3N4hmEqVex8P8jr4SkZWT0f-4i1epfZcRJmz6ognOCfaxa91c3qFNpG3IVY881g9aCPdLOxmU5FqKDPgHIZLvp8wWeTWdi_YQaAXMUh-yZQXBLhBimG8SR2iRj6ZTvu_L_Ytmc0QePkaijA6CB8wY2SbHlOGL2JUcEXKoNjC9dSSbkHqWx0tXMR2XCCdlhHPC1vGYcCgV-XQ_bfqgN7yn8" 
-d "\"referenceId:35f1f125-5d33-44a4-82fc-26734843c804\"" "https://webite.com:443/testing/api/devices/12345678/parentPath"
```

My expected output:

echo the command in an .sh file

```
curl -X PUT 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" 
--header "Accept: application/json" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer gAAAAJ1EY28EHByJCcgT-sWhzid-cxW1uQrfO1QJG52D4n9GYj9YWd4KUGBSxO2LXZ48eEbQivSAlM6bplNE82o84UFnkwiVJ0V1q4DM9VAHw6jU4UvkdhhSrlupC6gKl_RHEgf2cluwvAN11My7eFflA-JnBrINp02d146CaJrR_r52hAEAAIAAAAAXmL1IDoHPz3S5deta0ygANUUoEFBsuKHaeDo3NXVUptxxDXR00yaNmILqd1psJckYhrBhh7wdQNdNYaSsqgwsF8Nuw_hhUAbg27hhGaVLmbeK3eS3mtVlq1D73Vg3KSk-24DmR0o-jT2u88k4MLfkqxuipEsLAEcSoe4zAPE1jcch2GGvlNWTHN98gMxw-svmvu6hizZ1fe-pWNtMGwa9u_hVimOr8A-7HcidA4Sj_jBprulGUapifc-Dd_qZFj1FM1HedHvnu8NKzp_uRr8z_Myk0IO6RyqjPPufLdafV3N4hmEqVex8P8jr4SkZWT0f-4i1epfZcRJmz6ognOCfaxa91c3qFNpG3IVY881g9aCPdLOxmU5FqKDPgHIZLvp8wWeTWdi_YQaAXMUh-yZQXBLhBimG8SR2iRj6ZTvu_L_Ytmc0QePkaijA6CB8wY2SbHlOGL2JUcEXKoNjC9dSSbkHqWx0tXMR2XCCdlhHPC1vGYcCgV-XQ_bfqgN7yn8" 
-d "\"referenceId:35f1f125-5d33-44a4-82fc-26734843c804\"" "https://webite.com:443/testing/api/devices/12345678/parentPath"


curl -X PUT 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" 
--header "Accept: application/json" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer gAAAAJ1EY28EHByJCcgT-sWhzid-cxW1uQrfO1QJG52D4n9GYj9YWd4KUGBSxO2LXZ48eEbQivSAlM6bplNE82o84UFnkwiVJ0V1q4DM9VAHw6jU4UvkdhhSrlupC6gKl_RHEgf2cluwvAN11My7eFflA-JnBrINp02d146CaJrR_r52hAEAAIAAAAAXmL1IDoHPz3S5deta0ygANUUoEFBsuKHaeDo3NXVUptxxDXR00yaNmILqd1psJckYhrBhh7wdQNdNYaSsqgwsF8Nuw_hhUAbg27hhGaVLmbeK3eS3mtVlq1D73Vg3KSk-24DmR0o-jT2u88k4MLfkqxuipEsLAEcSoe4zAPE1jcch2GGvlNWTHN98gMxw-svmvu6hizZ1fe-pWNtMGwa9u_hVimOr8A-7HcidA4Sj_jBprulGUapifc-Dd_qZFj1FM1HedHvnu8NKzp_uRr8z_Myk0IO6RyqjPPufLdafV3N4hmEqVex8P8jr4SkZWT0f-4i1epfZcRJmz6ognOCfaxa91c3qFNpG3IVY881g9aCPdLOxmU5FqKDPgHIZLvp8wWeTWdi_YQaAXMUh-yZQXBLhBimG8SR2iRj6ZTvu_L_Ytmc0QePkaijA6CB8wY2SbHlOGL2JUcEXKoNjC9dSSbkHqWx0tXMR2XCCdlhHPC1vGYcCgV-XQ_bfqgN7yn8" 
-d "\"referenceId:5abd0360-c4be-4e69-8085-340755f87290\"" "https://webite.com:443/testing/api/devices/87654321/parentPath"
```

Or if you have a way (right syntax) so that I can curl directly, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `>>` instead of `>` when you want to append rather that overwrite.

```
..."$output1"/parentPath\" " > test.sh
```

Should be

```
..."$output1"/parentPath\" " >> test.sh
```

**Edit**: I think you can use something a little simpler than what you are doing:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r boy && read -r girl <&3; do
    # I omitted parts of the curl command with ...
    echo "curl -X PUT ... referenceId:$girl ...api/devices/$boy/" >> test.sh

done < boy.txt 3<girl.txt
```

Comment: Hi ssemilla, your great! after I've followed your answer, it echoed about 3xcurl-command (first second third). im not sure why. I only need two output. any ideas?

Comment: Well that is because you have an inner loop and based from the logic of your script, you will really have three outputs.

Comment: @ConfidentialCompany look at the updated code, your problem could be solved a little bit easier by reading the two files in the same loop.

Comment: Note that you probably need/want to remove any old copy of the output file in the top of the script (before the loop).  Otherwise, if you run it more than once, you'll keep appending to the same file.  Alternately, do the output redirect as `>test.sh` on the `done` line with your simplified example.

Comment: Hi ssemilla, im trying to understand and do reverse engineering on the script above. what does "<&3" mean? also this one "done < boy.txt 3<girl.txt"

Comment: The `done < boy.txt` sends the contents to `read -r boy`. `3<girl.txt` redirects the contents of `girl.txt` to the file descriptor `3`. `read -r girl <&3` reads the contents of the file descriptor `3`.

Comment: `<&3` means redirect the file descriptor `3` to `stdin`. You can read more on io redirection in https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html